# Sddm error multiple screens

Tags: xrandr, sddm

login screen gets overlapped like in the image [setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDxvj.jpg)

I've tried to put these lines in the /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup file  but it doesn't work

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-0 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal
```

and trying to tur off the laptop screen but it doesn't work either

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --off --output HDMI-0 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal
```

the script gets executed but I don't know why it doesn't work...
help:(

Comment: What OS/release please

Comment: ubuntu 19.04 kernel version 5.0.0-37-generic